# Simple join query for two queries:

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two Queries which are related to two identical tables (Column names and everything is same)

```
Query1: "SELECT * FROM Notifications ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";

Query2: "SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";
```

How to merge the results into one single cursor? I would want to have a join instead of merge cursor.

Comment: Okay I never knew there is something called as UNION, let me check that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select from the UNION of both tables. Note if you use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` then duplicate records will be deleted from the result set)

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM Notifications 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron
    ) T
ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)
```

Comment: This one is working for me, also I dont want duplicates so I would go with UNION.

Answer (score 2):

Use the UNION clause:

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Notifications UNION SELECT * FROM NotificationsCron) T ORDER BY SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0)>SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0), SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0)";
```

Note that the two tables MUST have the same columns - If not, then create fake columns inside the queries themselves by using aliases.

For reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_unions_clause.htm

Comment: I am getting: 1st ORDER BY term does not match any column in the result set

Comment: Try using an alias for SUBSTR(DATE('NOW'), 0) and for SUBSTR(DateToNotify, 0) in both SELECTs (must match)

Comment: @DerGolem:  You should use ORDER BY after you UNION tables not in each subquery. That is the reason of the error.

Comment: Corrected my answer -> like yours, but with UNION instead of UNION ALL. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use  UNION ALL Clause

exp:

```
SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
FROM table1 [, table2 ]
[WHERE condition]

UNION ALL

SELECT column1 [, column2 ]
FROM table1 [, table2 ]
[WHERE condition]
```